# Ignore some fields using the helper @Html.EditorForModel()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, models, mvc-editor-templates

I use helper `@Html.EditorForModel()` on all my views.

There is a desire that he skip two fields in my model, but only on this view, the other he must continue to display these fields as usual.

How can I skip these two fields only in this view?

Comment: @Nicholas, well its much better than mine! (alhough mine is quicker to put on forms/email addresses!)

Answer (score 32):

Use the `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` attribute.

E.g.

```
public class Person {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    ...
```

Solution and example sourced from: [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework, Third Edition](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=gzfFQrs_qQAC&lpg=PA263&ots=EXAdhjp7-M&dq=where%20is%20the%20editorformodel%20helper&pg=PA552#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend writing viewmodels for any view that you want to deviate from default behaviour.

Side note: It's probably a good idea to write a viewmodel for every view, as you get separation of concerns, and it's easier to control the behaviour of each view.

Anyway...

For example, say your model is

```cs
class Herps {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SecretToSomePeople { get; set; }
}
```

and you don't want to have `SecretToSomePeople` shown on one of your views, create a viewmodel that doesn't contain `SecretToSomePeople`

```cs
class Herps {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and use that as the model for the desired view. Make sure you copy to/from the actual model somewhere though.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, if you don't want to display the fields then they shouldn't be on the Model - the point of Models to to hold exactly the data required for the View.

Comment: There are two steps.
In the first step, the user fills only part of the information in the second it fills the rest.

The fields are displayed in another view;

Comment: I do not agree with you - this is a ViewModel and therefore it should contain all the data neccessary for the view to be displayed properly. It does not mean that all data should be edited/updated by the user.

Comment: @MaksymilianMajer: that's not what he's saying - he has a viewmodel with n fields on it, but only wants to show n-2 fields. The other two are irrelevant for this particular view. Nicholas Sizer explains it better below.

Comment: You are right. I wanted to stress out a situation when he might need those properties to affect how the view is rendered but still not be visible when using `EditorForModel()`. The original question doesn't eliminate this possibility but your answer does.